# Warnings: Illegal String Offset + Cannot Assign Empty String To String Offset

Tags: php, wordpress, php7

как можно пофиксить данные предупреждения возникшие с переходом на php 7.1?
Вот строки в которых возникают предупреждения:

Warning: Illegal string offset 'url'

```
$value = isset($meta['id']) ? $meta : $std;
if (!isset($value['url']))
    $value['url'] = '';
```

Illegal string offset 'id', Uninitialized string offset: 0, Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset

```
if (!isset($value['id']))
$value['id'] = '';
$value['url'] = isset($value['src'])? $value['src']: $value['url'];
```

Comment: `$value = isset($meta['id']) ? (array)$meta : (array)$std;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$value = isset($meta['id']) ? **(array)**$meta : **(array)**$std;

Answer (score 0):

У Вас есть функция проверяющая наличие значения. 
Синтаксис следующий:

```
if (!isset(переменная)){ // где !isset значит не существует.
    переменная = ''; // Добавляем значение переменной.
}
```

Пример:

```
if (!isset($value['url'])){
    $value['url'] = '';
}

if (!isset($value['id'])){ // Если не существует $value['id'], то Выполняем действие
    $value['id'] = '';
    if(isset($value['src']){ // Если не существует $value['src'], то Выполняем действие
        $value['url'] = $value['src']:
    } else { 
        $value['url'] = $value['url'];
    }
}
```